# Creating my own base_url() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I like `base_url()` so much that I want to create another global function `base_img_url()` where I can define the url in the `config.php` file just like `base_url()`. How do I do this and where should the function be? Is this a common practice?

Right now I'm just defining a constant in `constants.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are going right.

I am also doing the same, defining in constants.php file.

I do not think any other way, as you are expecting is possible.
Defining in constants file, is the best and easiest plus non-problematic way.

What can be wrong doing like this ?

Comment: To me, a constant makes sense.. unless for some strange reason the path is going to change mid-stream. The only difference is that you can pass arguments to a function, but having a function that just returns a static value seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any point in doing this because you are just saving typing 1 or 2 words by it. None the less, you can create a helper function, make it return the path and add it to autoload. Then call it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Go to constants.php
define('base_img_url', 'define constant path here');

and use likr that
variable = base_img_url.'/path for concat';